# How to fix a simple code to conditional mutate

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I need to create a new variable based on values in the old column in the data frame. If the existing value ends with .0, the new value in the new column will be 0 / But If the existing value ends with .1 the new value in the new column will be 1 / But the small code I used does not distinguish between 11.0 and 11.1 (and in other pairs with a similar pattern).

I attach an example and the unsuccessful solution

```
c<-c(1.1,1.0, 0.1, 0.0, 80.1, 80.0, 91.1, 91.0, 11.1,11.0)
b<-c(1,1,0,0,80,80,91,91,11,11)

cb<-data.frame(b,c) #this is exaple to my data

cb<-mutate(cb, a = ifelse(grepl( ".1" ,   cb$c ), 1, 0 )) #this is my unsuccessful solution

a<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
abc<-data.frame(a,c,b) # This is the desired result
```

As can be seen in the code, for values 81.0 and 11.0, an incorrect value of 1 was created instead of 0

Comment: (1) Don't use `cb$` inside `mutate`, just use the variable name. (2) It's really bad form to overload base R functions with variables, it can be confusing to look at `c` for eyes trained to see that as "concatenate". (3) Since you're using `dplyr`, you should use `if_else` instead, as it protects against things that base `ifelse` does not.

Comment: You need to learn about regular expressions. In regex-speak, `".1"` is "anything followed by a 1", where what I think you want is "decimal one". Try `"\\.1"` (double backslash).

Comment: However, that can and possibly will bite you in ways you have not considered yet, since `cb$c` is really a floating-point number. (When it bites you, you will get no indication other than "it won't work right".) If you read [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) (and/or read about IEEE-754), you'll see that sometimes that may convert to be `"\\.0999999999"` which will fail your test. Any test/comparison using floating-point should really be done with an inequality.

Comment: Your first suggestion (add //) works well with my simple data. I patiently passed all the data and there are no exceptions. I also checked the second solution:  if_else (abs (c %% 1 - 0.1) <1e-8, 1, 0)
Even  1e-8 is arbitrary, the results are the same. As usual, your answers are excellent. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex might be wrong, your `".1"` should really be `"\\.1"` to look for the literal dot.

Since your data is actually numeric, you really should be testing it numerically. Unfortunately (and this bites you whether numeric or grepl comparing), your `###.1` might internally convert to `###.09999999`, which will obviously fail. While you *could* in theory generate a regular expression that catches this mistake, that starts getting a bit complicated (https://xkcd.com/1171/). So, you should test it numerically.

But since it is floating point, doing something like

```r
if_else(c %% 1 == 0.1, 1, 0)
```

can fail for the same reason. A larger example:

```r
seq(0.1, 10.1)
#  [1]  0.1  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1  6.1  7.1  8.1  9.1 10.1
seq(0.1, 10.1) %% 1
#  [1] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1

### this is where it gets interesting
(seq(0.1, 10.1) %% 1) == 0.1
#  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
(seq(0.1, 10.1) %% 1) - 0.1
#  [1]  0.000000e+00  8.326673e-17  8.326673e-17  8.326673e-17 -3.608225e-16 -3.608225e-16 -3.608225e-16 -3.608225e-16
#  [9] -3.608225e-16 -3.608225e-16 -3.608225e-16
```

In reality, anything with `numeric` (floating-point) should focus on tests of inequality vice equality, for reasons suggested in [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) (and IEEE-754). Long-story-short: because digital storage has a limit on precision, it is feasible you will never get precisely the number you want when comparing. (You might get it right 99.9% of the time, but that 0.1% will test incorrectly *with no indication to you*.)

Consider a test of inequality:

```r
if_else(abs(c %% 1 - 0.1) < 1e-8, 1, 0)
# or just
1L * (abs(c %% 1 - 0.1) < 1e-8)

### using the demo from above
abs(seq(0.1, 10.1) %% 1 - 0.1) < 1e-8
#  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

My choice of `1e-8` is arbitrary and merely a starting point, as it depends on the type of data you have. Since your comparison-scale is "0.1", then frankly you could use `abs(c %% 1 - 0.1) < 0.01`. The smallest you can get with practical use is `.Machine$double.eps` (see [`?.Machine`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/.Machine) for definition of its properties), though I find in many applications that something orders-of-magnitude larger is still fine.

N.B.: **generally-speaking**, this depends entirely on the domain of the numbers, so please don't blindly use `1e-8` without understanding the premise and consequences of choosing the wrong boundary.

(And I stand by my comment: typing and using a variable named `c` just ... makes my brain hurt :-)

Comment: Thank you for turning my attention. I was not aware of it. I did so.